# Where to see which Firefox version is running? (64-bit or 32-bit)

Tags: windows, firefox, 64-bit

I downloaded Firefox version 43.0.4, 64-bit from their official site and installed it. Before this, I had the Firefox 32-bit version.  My OS is Windows 10, 64-bit.

I did not remove the 32-bit old version, just installed a fresh new 64-bit.  When I run the browser, I don't see information anywhere confirming that I'm running the 64-bit version.

Can you tell me where I can find information about the bit version of the browser that is being run?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Firefox, type `about:support` in the the URL window.  If you have the menu display turned on, this is also accessible under `Help | Troubleshooting Information`.  The `Application Basics` section at the top will show you the version you're running.

#### User Agent

Now that the 64-bit version has been officially released, it carries the same version number as the 32-bit version.  So if the version numbers on your computer are the same, you can determine 32-bit vs. 64-bit from the User Agent entry in that section:

- 32-bit Firefox running on 64-bit Windows (8.1, can't verify 10), shows WOW64 in the User Agent.
- 64-bit Firefox running on 64-bit Windows (8.1, can't verify 10), shows Win64; x64.
- 32-bit Firefox running on 32-bit Windows will not include the Win64; x64 in the user agent.

#### Control Panel

Another place you can differentiate them is the `Control Panel | Programs and Features | Uninstall a program`.  The software name is listed (the version number, 43.0 in this example, may be different):

- 32-bit Firefox is listed as Mozilla Firefox 43.0 (x86 en-US).
- 64-bit Firefox is listed as Mozilla Firefox 43.0 (x64 en-US).

If you have something other than the US English version, the letters after the x86 or x64 will be different.  (Source: [How to tell if Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.404techsupport.com/2015/12/tell-firefox-32-64/))

#### Task Manager

One other place to check, [according to Caspid on the Mozilla Support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/954794), is the Task Manager.

- Start the Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc).
- 32-bit Firefox will display as `firefox.exe *32`.

user559862 reported (in a now deleted post), that 64 bit Firefox is displayed as simply firefox.exe in the Task Manager.

Update:

#### Build Platform Target

It looks like there's yet another place to identify this, which you found, and I'll add it here for completeness.  If you enter the URL `about:buildconfig` (which also has a link in the Application Basics section), it has a section called `Build Platform Target`.  This includes a similar identification indicator.  A 64-bit Firefox will include the identifier `x86_64`.

Comment: Thanks! I found that Windows use 32bit version instead 64 bit. Also me help this tab **about:buildconfig**

Comment: @dimawebmaker: Are you referring to the Build Platform Target on about:buildconfig?  I'm running Linux, and mine shows up as **x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu**, which is consistent with my User Agent entry: **Linux x86_64**.  Looks like my package manager upgraded to 64-bit automatically when it became available for Linux.  Interesting.  There are supposed to be issues with 32-bit add-ons (only 64-bit add-ons work with 64-bit Firefox).  I've had a ton of add-ons forever and all still work, so apparently, that's more of a theoretical issue.  (cont'd)

Comment: BTW, your problem with still running 32-bit may be your original shortcut, and/or your default browser still pointing to the old version.

Answer (score 3):

#### How to tell if Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit

> Mozilla published the Windows 64-bit installer for Firefox to the
>   Download page with yesterday’s release of Firefox 43.0. You must have
>   a 64-bit version of Windows to take advantage of the new version of
>   the browser.
>
> There are two cosmetic bugs with the 64-bit version of Firefox that
>   have been posted for a while without resolution.
>
> - The first bug
>     addresses installing the 64-bit bit version of Firefox when you have
>     an existing 32-bit version installed. The installer will upgrade
>     Firefox to the 64-bit version but install it to C:\Program Files
>     (x86), breaking Windows conventions of installing 64-bit applications
>     to C:\Program Files.
> - The second bug is asking for a designation of
>     which bit browser you are using in Firefox’s Help, About.
>
> Since both of those bugs make it difficult to tell which version of
>   the browser you are using, here are two different ways to identify
>   32-bit vs 64-bit Firefox. User Agent
>
> In Firefox type `about:support` into the address bar. This will open up
>   a page with a lot of information about your browser. From the User
>   Agent line under Application Basics, you can see if this is the 32-bit
>   version or 64-bit version running.
>
> **The 32-bit Firefox running on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 shows WOW64 in the
>   User Agent.**
>
> [image: firefox43_x86]
>
> **The 64-bit Firefox running on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 shows Win64; x64.**
>
> [image: firefox43_x64]
>
> The 32-bit Firefox running on a 32-bit Windows will not include the
>   Win64; x64 in the user agent.
>
> **Programs and Features**
>
> Another place that you can check is the Control Panel, Programs and
>   Features. To uninstall a program, you can see the software name
>   listed.
>
> **The 32-bit Firefox is listed as Mozilla Firefox 43.0 (x86 en-US).**
>
> [image: firefox43_x86_programs]
>
> **The 64-bit Firefox is listed as Mozilla Firefox 43.0 (x64 en-US).**
>
> [image: firefox43_x64_programs]

Source [How to tell if Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.404techsupport.com/2015/12/tell-firefox-32-64/)

Answer (score 1):

This is being added to the About dialog in Firefox 51, as tracked in [bug 597738](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=597738):

[image]
[image]

(Screenshots by Chris Peterson attached to the Bugzilla bug.)

Answer (score 0):

More then likely the browser is 32-bit unless you have downloaded an unofficial build. Firefox has a 64-bit Nightly build, but this build is for testers and not for day-to-day use.

The easy way to check is via the install directory.

- (32-bit apps) - `C:\Program Files (x86)`
- (64-bit apps) - `C:\Program Files`

Comment: It's actually official as of 12/15/2015, see [press release](https://blog.mozilla.org/press/2015/12/firefox-64-bit-for-windows-available/).  It's downloadable from the ["all" downloads page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/).

Comment: There is a bug in the first release of the 64 bit version. The installer will upgrade Firefox to the 64-bit version but install it to C:\Program Files (x86), breaking Windows conventions of installing 64-bit applications to C:\Program Files. Source https://www.404techsupport.com/2015/12/tell-firefox-32-64/

Comment: @DavidPostill: I also read that it is supposed to upgrade Firefox to 64-bit (looks like we found the same 404 Tech Support reference).  However, the OP reports that the 32-bit version is still there and it is what is being run after the 64-bit installation (see their comment on my answer).  Any thoughts?  I wonder if the "upgrade to 64-bit" wording just means that the 64-bit version is installed, and it is an upgrade over the 32-bit version.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not exactly sure. I don't use standard install locations (I use `c:\apps\firefox` and I backed up the 32 bit version and chose to install the 64 bit version in the same directory. So I don't know if a default 64 bit install will also install "over the top"

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm also running Windows 7 64 bit if that makes a difference.