# All browsers do not see Java JRE at Windows 8.1

Tags: browser, java, java-applet

I am unable to run any Java applet in all browsers. Internet pages containing applets (or like that) says like "JRE is not installed on your machine. Install JRE and retry" or they just shows nothing.

Here is a fresh Windows 8.1 x64 for single language. There is none administrative politics I believe because I installed it personally. I turned off Windows firewall and Defener's real-time protection. Then installed `jre-8u77-windows-x64.exe`:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin>java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Java is enabled in browsers:

[image]

Now I'm verifying if Java installed with https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp ...

**Firefox 45.0.2**

— No Java presented at the Plugins page `about:addons`. At Java.com I press "Agree and continue". Next, I'm told "Java is disabled or not installed".

**Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m**

— There is no Java listed at `chrome://plugins/`. Java.com says "The Chrome browser does not support NPAPI plug-ins and therefore will not run all Java content. Switch to a different browser (Firefox, Internet Explorer or Safari on Mac) to run the Java plug-in."

**IE 11** (updated automatically)

— At Java.com I press "Agree and continue". The applet does not appear.

P.S. I tried to instal JRE 7 also

Comment: Are you running the 64bit version of Firefox?

Comment: I don't know. There is no such choice, and no such details in "about".

Comment: [Where to see which Firefox version is running? (64-bit or 32-bit)](http://superuser.com/q/1023356)

Comment: @DavidPostill, thank you much! After your point I installed 32-bit JRE and it works now. If you add an answer I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: Answer added ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I am unable to run any Java applet in all browsers.

**Firefox:**

Firefox 64 bit does not support the JRE at all.

Firefox 32 still supports the JRE (but support will be withdrawn during 2016). You have to install the **32 bit JRE** for this to work.

> Mozilla intends to remove support for most NPAPI plugins in Firefox by the end of 2016. Firefox began this process several years ago with manual plugin activation, allowing users to activate plugins only when they were necessary. This decision mirrors actions by other modern browsers, such as Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, which have already removed support for legacy plugins.
>
> Moreover, since new Firefox platforms do not have to support an existing ecosystem of users and plugins, new platforms such as 64-bit Firefox for Windows will launch without plugin support.

Source [NPAPI Plugins in Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/)

**Chrome**

Chrome no longer supports the JRE.

> Java is a NPAPI plugin.
>
> NPAPI plugins are being phased out of Chrome 42. Please note that Chrome will not support NPAPI plugins sometime after April 2015, therefore any websites that use these plugins will all stop working:  It will get more difficult to run NPAPI plugins in Chrome.

Source [Java Plugins disappear after new Chrome update to Version 42.0.2311.90 m](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/m5sRq0_UKek)